# What can you do with integers in GLSL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

There seems to be an extremely limited amount of things you can do with integers in GLSL ES 2.0.

For example:

- No bitwise operations are supported.
- No intrinsic functions seems to accept `int` types

So, it seems the only thing you can really do with integers is:

- Assign integer to integer
- Access array element by index
- Basic arithmetic (`-`, `+`, `*`, `/`), but only between other integers. No operator exists which allows you to add a `float` and `int` together.
- Compare them between each other.
- Convert them to other types
- `vec` constructors allow you to pass integers

Is that really it? Are there *any* intrinsic functions that take `int` parameters other than `vec` constructors? Are there *any* operations you can do between `float` and `int`?

Comment: If you can convert between the two, what else do you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, use cases of integers are limited. Per [OpenGL ES Shading Language spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf), 4.1.3:

> Integers are mainly supported as a programming aid. At the hardware level, real integers would aid efficient implementation of **loops** and **array indices**, and **referencing texture units**. However, there is no requirement **that integers in the language map to an integer type in hardware**. It is not expected that underlying hardware has full support for a wide range of integer operations. An OpenGL ES Shading Language implementation may convert integers to floats to operate on them. Hence, there is no portable wrapping behavior.

Since there's no guarantee GLSL ES integer type maps to a hardware integer type, it's only useful for **compile-time type checking** with little to no effect at runtime. All places that **require** integers are listed in the spec.